# Is it possible to write the expression with with async and Null-conditional operators ?. briefly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a method

```
public async Task<bool> ExistMyCookie()
```

I want to call the method with a null check. How its's a local function

```
async Task<bool> LocalExistCookie()
{
     if (m_browser != null)
        return await m_browser?.ExistMyCookie();
     return false;
}
```

I try to convert the function to an expression with Null-conditional operator ?. and ??. For example

```
cookie = await m_browser?.ExistMyCookie() ?? false;
```

I tried different variations of this expression, but the compiler raises errors.
Is it possible to write the short expression?

Comment: why? no ones going to be impressed if you convert 3 lines to 1. In fact I would argue anything like this just makes your code harder to read and therefore shouldn't be done.

Comment: You can compress this (and other operations) into one line easily (and readably) if you ensure `m_browser` is never `null`. This can be done by using a [null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) (that is, not a `null`, just a `Browser` that yields sensible defaults). Whether this is more or less appropriate than null checks will depend on the rest of your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use the null conditional and null coalescing operators with `await`, but it doesn't look particularly pretty:

```
return await (m_browser?.ExistMyCookie() ?? Task.FromResult(false));
```

`await m_browser?.ExistMyCookie()` by itself will cause a NRE if `m_browser` is `null`; this is because `m_browser?.ExistMyCookie()` is evaluated first, and may end up with a `null` `Task<bool>`. So the `??` operator must be applied at that level to ensure the *task* is not `null`.

That said, I would prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66565503/263693), slightly modified to remove the unnecessary null conditional operator:

```
return m_browser != null ? await m_browser.ExistMyCookie() : false;
```

Comment: I agree, but slightly modified too: return m_browser != null && await m_browser.ExistMyCookie() ;

Comment: @PavelIvchenkov IMHO your version requires more mental effort to comprehend, compared to either of  Stephen Cleary's versions.

Answer (score 2):

```
cookie = m_browser != null ? await m_browser.ExistMyCookie() : false;
```